# SMB mount fails with execl()

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, mount, smb, cifs

To mount CIFS presently I use system() call in source, this works. If I try to run command manually on shell it works too.

```
$ mount -t cifs //IP/dir /mnt -o user=name,pass=PASS,domain=mydomain,nounix
$ mount.cifs //IP/dir /mnt -o user=name,pass=PASS,domain=mydomain,nounix
```

But if i replace the same command with exec() family i see errors.

```
if(fork() == 0) 
{
  if (execl("/bin/mount", "/bin/mount", "-t", "cifs", "//IP/dir",  "/mnt", 
  "-o user=name,pass=PASS,domain=mydomain,nounix", (char*) NULL) < 0)
  ...
}
else
  ...
```

Error: mount: mounting cifs on //IP/dir /mnt failed: No such file or directory. It looks like mount directory "/mnt" is not recognized or not seen by mount process.

Tried below things but no luck:

- as suggested in forums tried using sec=ntlmv2 and other options
- with mount.cifs
- combined arguments "//IP/dir" and "/mnt" as "//ipaddr/dir  /mnt"

What would be the cause here? How to see the command line parameters of the exec()'ed program ?

Version of mount:

```
mount.cifs version: 1.14-x
```

Regards, - AK

Comment: Try to delimit *-o* option from its value in `execl` call: `..., "-o", "user=name,..."`. This is how `mount` command interpret it when called from shell.

Comment: Separated the params: "-o", "user=name,..." 


Didn't work :(

Comment: getting the error:      


mount: mounting cifs on //IPaddr/userdir   /mnt  failed:  No such file or directory

Comment: Hmm, actually *mounting cifs on //IP/dir /mnt failed: No such file or directory* means that there is no directory `//IP/dir /mnt`, so you cannot combine two dirs arguments in one.

Comment: Presently SMB mount is done using `system("mount.cifs  .....")`.

I just need to replace use of `system()` call for mounting. So are there any options other than using `execl ( )` ?

Comment: `execl()` with appropriate arguments should be equivalent to `system()`. You can write simple program, which simply prints its parameters, and pass it to `execl` as the first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `strace()` to find the arguments passed to `execl()`. Solved my issue by using system calls `mount()` and `umount()`.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have installed samba

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

In the Global section of the file /etc/samba/smb.conf you should have this :-

```
workgroup = WORKGROUP
netbios name = PCNAME
name resolve order = bcast host
```

Change WORKGROUP and PCNAME accordingly. Set the name resolve order as shown in order to browse windows shares using Nautilus.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I use this mount command on embedded application. The application mounts the SMB share so that it can copy some data to SMB server. 
I checked /etc/ directory, there is no entry for samba or smb or cifs. The linux kernel is cross compiled for ARM with SMB included.

I just need to replace system() call with execl() or equivalent for mounting.